# Prevent file renaming

Tags: files

I have a user who is uploading a number of files with the same file name. It is important to them that the files are never renamed. However, the files are getting _1, _2, etc on the end.

Is there a way I can ask Drupal to make a new directory for duplicate file names so that a rename is not necessary?

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways you can do this:

1. The [Upload File Replace](http://drupal.org/project/upload_replace) module. A small utility module that automatically stops Drupal from renaming new files upload via filefield CCK. When 2 files with the same name exist, the older files will be renamed.
2. Specify an optional subdirectory within the field setting where files will be stored using a unique token in the file path settings. (e.g. [current-date:raw])